# Hidden form doesn't show up on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On button click, I am trying to display a form which is hidden. However, I do not understand why it is not showing up.

I've tried the following code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button_id").click(function() {
    $("#form_id").show(); //Form shows on button click
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Myapp</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" name="button" value="button" id="button_id" onclick="ready();">
  <form id="form_id" action="" method="POST" style="display:none;">
    <input type="id" name="login[id]" placeholder="id"><br>
    <input type="username" name="login[username]" placeholder="username"><br>
    <input type="password" name="login[password]" placeholder="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">
  </form><br>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you loading jQuery? What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: Where do you define `ready()`? Why do you use both `onclick=` and `$("#button_id").click()`

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @j08691 - I am not getting any errors in the console. Also, can you add more information on "loading jQuery"? I am using what I found on the internet.

Comment: @Barmar - I tried it with the  onclick = and without it too still the form doesn't display when I hit the button. I am not getting any errors in the console. I have defined the ready() in the script tag in the head tag

Comment: You need to load the jQuery library in your code before you can use jQuery. E.g. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @j08691 - I did that right now still the form isn't displayed.

Comment: So you weren't doing it before now? And you claim you had no errors in the console? How are you checking the console?

Comment: If you didn't load jQuery, the code `$(document).ready(...)` should have caused an error saying that `$` is not a function.

Comment: The code in the snippet shows the form, then it gets an error because of `onclick="ready()"`, so you must be doing something different from what you posted.

Comment: @j08691 - application.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
./app/javascript/packs/application.js @ application.js:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83

Comment: @Barmar - Sorry I removed the ready(); and ran it so I couldn't see the error you mentioned but yes it does show up when I put the onclick = "ready();". Please look at the error above and let me know what I can do

Comment: Make sure you load jQuery before you load bootstrap.

Comment: @Barmar - Oh okay. I am doing this in my view of rails app in my html.erb file and have a bootstrap gem. I will try putting the jQuery code in the application.js file if that could help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onclick="ready();"` from your button's HTML as that attribute is:

1. Not needed because you've already set up the `click` handler with your JQuery.
2. References a non-existent `ready()` function and causes an error.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button_id").click(function() {
    $("#form_id").show(); //Form shows on button click
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input type="button" name="button" value="button" id="button_id">
  <form id="form_id" action="" method="POST" style="display:none;">
    <input type="id" name="login[id]" placeholder="id"><br>
    <input type="username" name="login[username]" placeholder="username"><br>
    <input type="password" name="login[password]" placeholder="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: I did remove the ready and I am still getting the below error
application.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
./app/javascript/packs/application.js @ application.js:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83

Comment: Then you do not have JQuery referenced or referenced properly. Since the error indicates that you are using WebPack, I'd start there.

Comment: This html page is in the view of my rials app (Its an .htm;.erb file). I did however meet all the requirements of the ruby gems for jquery in my rails app and have kept jquery on top of bootstrap so that it is loaded 1st. Also my console no longer shows any errors. Even so the hidden form isn't showing up.

Comment: Through the comments, we've discovered that your code is much more complex than what you've initially shared. Please update your question with all pertinent information and add the appropriate tags as well.